# what is the Pythonic way to implement a __str__ method with different format options?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I'd like to create a `__str__` method that creates the string in various formats according to user choice.

The best I have come up with is to make a `__str__(**kwargs)` method, and this seems to work ok, but it isn't compatible with `str(obj)` or `print(obj)`. In other words I have to use `print(obj.__str__(style='pretty'))` rather than `print(obj, style='pretty')`.

Comment: Take `**kwargs` in the constructor rather than the function itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implement the [`object.__format__()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__) instead, and a user can then specify the formatting required with the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) and [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print(format(obj, 'pretty'))
```

or

```
print('This object is pretty: {:pretty}'.format(obj))
```

You probably want to delegate most of the handling of the format on to `str.__format__`:

```
def __format__(self, spec):
    if spec.endswith('pretty'):
        prettified = self.pretty_version()
        return prettified.__format__(spec[:-6])
    return str(self).__format__(spec)
```

That way you can still support all the field width and padding alignment options that the default `str.__format__` method supports.

Demo:

```
>>> class Foo():
...     def __str__(self):
...         return 'plain foo'
...     def pretty_version(self):
...         return 'pretty foo'
...     def __format__(self, spec):
...         if spec.endswith('pretty'):
...             prettified = self.pretty_version()
...             return prettified.__format__(spec[:-6])
...         return str(self).__format__(spec)
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> print(f)
plain foo
>>> print(format(f))
plain foo
>>> print(format(f, 'pretty'))
pretty foo
>>> print(format(f, '>20pretty'))
          pretty foo
>>> print('This object is pretty: {:^20pretty}!'.format(f))
This object is pretty:      pretty foo     !
```

Comment: This works great, but it behaves unexpectedly when my pretty string is multi line. If one line, then >20 tabs the string over like your example... but if multi line, it has no effect. Do you have a possible solution?

Comment: @KeithLucas: You'd have to apply the formatting manually to each line then; `str.__format__` doesn't support applying field widths to separate lines.