# How can I add custom formatters to my classes similar to datetime?

Tags: python, string-formatting

With datetime objects, you can use `.format` in a special way:

```
from datetime import datetime
'{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M}'.format(datetime(1990, 4, 28, 22, 30))
```

Those are [the usual formatters](http://strftime.org/) for datetime objects.

Can I give any class such custom ways to format them? How?

Comment: The dupe target refers to string formatting only.  This question seems to be for an object of arbitrary class, although the title makes it sound like it's about `datetime`.  I'd say this isn't a dupe, but the title should be edited.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 I tried improve the title.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 https://stackoverflow.com/a/19864463/846892. `__format__` is decently known, you could find more dupes easily, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28904602/846892

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the answer on https://pyformat.info/:

**Yes**

```
class HAL9000(object):

    def __format__(self, format):
        if (format == 'open-the-pod-bay-doors'):
            return "I'm afraid I can't do that."
        return 'HAL 9000'
```